# Записать в базу данных SQlite спарсенные данные через CURL PHP

Tags: sqlite, curl

Здравствуйте. Ломаю голову уже 4 дня. Перерыл ввесь интернет и ни одного мануала нигде не нашел касательно моего запроса. Есть скрипт curl (ниже приведу пример) который парсит инфу с другого сайта. Необходимо чтоб полученные данные записывались в базу данных SQlite моего сайта. Помогите демонстрацией кода, который создаст базу данных и занесет эти данные в нее, ну или хотябы подскажите как это сделать? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Скрипт парсера на CURL:

```
<?php
$___notjson=1;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$ch = curl_init('https://www.worldcoinindex.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
require ('phpQuery.php');
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
$btc = $doc->find('#myTable .bitcoin span:eq(3)')->html();
$ef = $doc->find('#myTable .ethereum span:eq(3)')->html();
$dsh = $doc->find('#myTable .dash span:eq(3)')->html();
echo '<div class="blockcoin">';
echo '<span class="coin">' .'1 BTC = '. $btc .' $' .'</span>';
echo '<span class="coin">' .'1 ETH = '. $ef .' $' .'</span>';
echo '<span class="coin3">' .'1 DSH = '. $dsh .' $' .'</span>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Т.е. ваш вопрос можно свести к тому, как с помощью PHP записать данные в SQlite базу?

Comment: А SQL вы знаете?

Comment: Да именно, с помощью PHP записать данные в SQlite. SQlite изучаю, но из всех мануалов и видеоуроков что есть в сети, есть только для простых запросов по типу записать в базу данных юзера, "id, name, password". По данным урокам я не могу понять, как применить чтоб мой скрипт записывал в базу данных переменные: $btc, $ef, $dsh и там их хранил.

Comment: Вопрос решил сам